# Smarty PHP insert functions

Tags: php, smarty

I'd like to include a subtemplate within a main template. This subtemplate should be rendered by a php function (I need to access the db). I've seen in the guide that {insert} tag is what I should be looking for as include_php is deprecated.

Now, I have the following file in what should be the default plugin directory (/templates/plugins):

```
<?php

    // /templates/plugins/insert.admin_items.php

    require_once('lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

    function smarty_insert_admin_items($params, &$smarty)
    {
        /* fetch items */

       // render page
       $smarty = new Smarty();
       $smarty->assign('items', $sorted_items);
       return $smarty->fetch('admin_items.tpl');    
    }
 ?>
```

The subtemplate to be included:

```
<!-- /templates/admin_items.tpl -->
<div>
  {foreach $items as $i}
    <div>{$i.title}</div>
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

This is the main template

```
<!-- /templates/admin.tpl -->
<html>
    <body>
       {insert name="admin_items"}
   </body>
</html>
```

And how I call it

```
// /admin.php
<?php
    require_once('lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

    $smarty = new Smarty();
    $smarty->display('admin.tpl');
?>
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "./templates/admin.tpl" on line 10 "{insert name=&quot;admin_items&quot;}" {insert} no function or plugin found for 'admin_items'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:431 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_insert.php(92): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('{insert} no fun...', 10) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(284): Smarty_Internal_Compile_Insert->compile(Array, Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), Array, NULL, NULL) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(123): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->callTagCompiler('insert', Array, Array) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2319): Smarty_Internal_TemplateC in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 431
```

Notice that without using the subtemplate / insert thing (fetching the data from admin.php and rendering it in admin.tpl) it works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[{insert}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.insert.tpl) needs to be called in conjunction of a plugin or function if what you want is to include another template use [{include}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl)

**EDIT:** Also be sure to include the complete path to you included template starting from your template directory.